# How to specify default `RangeExpression` function parameter?

Tags: swift, parameters, range, parameter-passing

I'd like a function to work with all types of ranges of `Int`: open, closed, half-open.
So I define it like this:

```
func asciiOnly<R: RangeExpression>(_ name: String, lengthRange: R =  (3...18 as! R)) -> Bool where R.Bound == Int {
    guard  lengthRange ~= name.count , name.first!.isLetter else { return false }
    return name.allSatisfy{ $0.isASCII }
}
```

It mostly works except the fact that I can't omit `lengthRange` parameter when calling the function.

```
asciiOnly("tom_c", lengthRange: 3...)   // Works 
asciiOnly("tom3️⃣", lengthRange: 3...18) // Works
asciiOnly("tomё", lengthRange: 3..<19)  // Works
asciiOnly("tom3")    // Error: Generic parameter 'R' could not be inferred
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how default value for `lengthRange` can be implemented for such a case?

Comment: Why do you need a range expression if you don't use it when checking your string? Btw `asciiOnly("tom3️⃣", lengthRange: 1...2)` returns `false`. Do you really think it "works"? IMO this is unexpected behavior

Comment: I'm using a `lengthRange` not to check string but to check that length of the string is within range bounds. For this particular case two parameters `minLength` and `maxLength` would be a better design decision. But there could be cases when we would need to pass range expression and have some default one too. As for "3️⃣" symbol - it is not an ASCII, so string containing it is not an ASCII string.

Comment: But 1…2 looks like should be checking just the second and third characters. Don’t use a range just pass a length

Comment: If you need to pass a range and a closed range just create the related methods as well

Comment: Seems like the only way for now, though it is quite verbose, @Leo.